# Formula to convert tensorflow padding values to caffe padding values?

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, convolution

I am trying to understand the padding differences for caffe and tensorflow.

I have read the following articles:

https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/wiki/Error-in-mobilenet-conversion-from-Tensorflow-to-Caffe-Different-way-of-padding
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1318

From these I understand that tensorflow does asymmetric padding and caffe does symmetrical padding.

My question is - if you have the padding values for a convolution layer for a tensorflow model how do you convert these to the equivalent padding values in a caffe convolution layer?
What is the formula?

```
For example (Tensorflow model):

Input = 224x112x3

Convolution - 7x7x64 ; stride 2; SAME padding

Output size = 112x56x64
```

The tensorflow paddings are (asymmetric):

```
Padding top   : 2
Padding bottom: 3
Padding left  : 2
Padding right : 3
```

What would these padding values be in caffe and is there a general formula to calculate them?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such formula. If you trapped into asymmetric padding with tensorflow (i.e. padding is different between top-bottom), there is no way to reproduce this in Caffe. See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn/issues/153#issuecomment-387982630) for more details.

In order to avoid this problem I would recommend to prepend the convolutions with an explicit symmetric padding (via tf.pad) and make them 'valid', not 'same'. Of course, this is only possible if you desing and train the model by yourself.